# Enumerate Entire LinqToSql Object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have database with 100+ tables that is heavily normalized, and the data doesn't change frequently. I'm using LinqToSql and to encapsulate some simple debugging and queries so that the entire DB design doesn't need to be understood to get data. I'm trying to enable quick prototyping without really caring about the performance.

Is there a simple way to Enumerate the entire LinqToSql object into a read only container in memory? A cache from a point in time would be fine too, if something like that exists. Its going to be big and I fully realize that.

```
using (Context db = new Context())
{
   var a = db.Table1s.AsEnumerable();
   var b = db.Table2s.AsEnumerable();

   var q = a.Where(x => x.SomeComplexMethod())
            .Join(b...)
}
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
using (Context db = new Context())
{
   var enumerated = db.Materialize();   

   var q = enumerated.Table1s()
                     .Where(x => x.SomeComplexMethod())
                     .Join(enumerated.Table2s...)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to make read-only but wouldn't Entity Framework provide you with most of the functionality you're after? http://www.asp.net/entity-framework

Comment: @Mark do you want to create c# POCOS that can be used as model classes AFAIK LinqToSql does not create the POCOS, you need to add the dbml separately to the project. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/892233/POCO-Generator does this answer your requirement

Comment: POCOS are used for the real deal, but they're more work to do correctly.  This isn't for production, just something quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way that I can think of is reflection, with extension method like this you will be able to get all objects in once:

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IQueryable> GetAllDbSets(this DbContext context)
    {
        return context.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                        && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
            .Select(p => (IQueryable)p.GetValue(context));
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var allTables = context.GetAllDbSets();

    var allTablesInMemory = context.GetAllDbSets()
                 .Select(q => Enumerable.ToArray((dynamic)q))
                 .ToArray();

    var allValuesInArray = context.GetAllDbSets()
                 .SelectMany<dynamic,dynamic>(q => Enumerable.ToArray(q))
                 .ToArray();
}
```

But in any case it should not considered as good approach to work with database.

Comment: Thanks.  Then I can use reflection to get the "names" of the stuff in the return Array.